# Delete Attr and add it if class exist - jquery

Tags: jquery, each, attr

Hello I have a problem with this small code:

```
$(".delayDiv").each(function(){
    var img_attr = $(this).attr('style');
    $(this).attr('style', '');
    if ($(".delayDiv").hasClass("visible")) {
        $(this).attr('style', img_attr);
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- Look for Divs with `class="delayDiv"`
- then save the style attribute in a variable
- then, search for the class="visible" in the same div (I'm adding this
  class using viewportChecker.js, that means the class is added only if
  the Div is inside the viewport).
- If the class exist, add the style content again!

> DIV outsite the viewport: `<div class="backImg"></div>`
>
> DIV inside the viewport: `<div class="backImg visible"></div>`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the style only if element do not have `'visible'` class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delayDiv").each(function(){
        if (!$(".delayDiv").hasClass("visible")) {
            $(this).removeAttr('style', '');
        }
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a `:not()` selector and `removeAttr()` to remove the style from all the main class that doesn't also have the visible class

```
$(".delayDiv:not(.visible)").removeAttr('style')
```